# static page name and search engine SEO

Tags: static, seo

I want generate static pages from database.

What is a better suggestion that a better page's name for search engine SEO?

As my articles have a few articles with same title,  So combine title with article ID or article creat date maybe a good way. Or the page's name is not matter for a search engine SEO. just write key words in `<meta>`?

Another question. How many letters in the name of page for SEO is better? Is there have a shoter or longest limited?

Waiting for a better suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If its a blog using date is a good option along with title. At later point date will serve in segregating old/fresh blogs and even users would be able to relate if information is stale.
2. From SEO perspective suggest to avoid duplicate titles.
3. Have URLs which can include your target keyword (I assume its title here). Readable & shorter the URL its better.